# Why does my transform: scale() property move the image to the left?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to make an image gallery that uses CSS animations, but I'm having some weird effects come up. I have a smaller thumbnail image to start, and I want it to scale to twice the size when I hover over it. That part works, but it also makes it move to the left, and it ends up going over the edge of the screen. What should I do to fix it?

```css
.zoom {
    transition:1s ease-in-out;
}
.zoom:hover {
    transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="zoom">
        <img alt="Paperplane" src="Paperplane.png" style="width: 200px; height: 62px">
        <br> <span class="caption">A paper plane</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3b7afm7z/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not moving to the left. The left *edge* is moving, however, as is the right. Because your content is left-aligned, it appears to move left. This colorized demo shows it well:

```css
.zoom {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  background: pink;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="zoom">
    <img alt="Paperplane" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" style="width: 200px; height: 62px" />
    <br /> <span class="caption">A paper plane</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

You could set the transform origin:

```
transform-origin: left top;
```

```css
.zoom {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  background: pink;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="zoom">
    <img alt="Paperplane" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" style="width: 200px; height: 62px" />
    <br /> <span class="caption">A paper plane</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Also consider simply using a less dramatic transform:

```
transform: scale(1.1);
```

```css
.zoom {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  background: pink;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="zoom">
    <img alt="Paperplane" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" style="width: 200px; height: 62px" />
    <br /> <span class="caption">A paper plane</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you need immutable area of image, you can try add overflow:hidden container.

For this example use class content before zoom class:

```
.content{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3b7afm7z/6/

---

and you can combine both, for this example entry:

```
.content{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.zoom:hover {
    transform:scale(2);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3b7afm7z/9

Answer (score 1):

As isherwood described, the error is due to the fact that `.zoom` is taking up the full width, not just the visible part.

Another solution would be size `.zoom` so that it only takes up the amount of space that you want, in this case the width of the image. You can do this by giving it an explicit width.

```
.zoom {
    transition:1s ease-in-out;
    width:200px;
}
```

However, since the element still transforms from the middle, it will still go outside of the viewport since it's so close. To remedy this, you could use `transform-origin:left` or provide enough room on either side so that the scaled version does not go outside of the viewport. I used padding to do so in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3b7afm7z/5/).

One other note: it's not good to scale things past their default value, `scale(1)`, because they become blurry from being too big. As a result, you could size your elements to `width:400px;` and give it `transform:scale(.5)` by default and go to `transform:scale(1)` on hover and it'd remove this issue.

[Demo with all the changes](http://jsfiddle.net/3b7afm7z/7/)

Also note that embedded styles are ***bad***, you should use the external stylesheet nearly all of the time.